# How to change the transparent background grid in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

When a layer in GIMP is transparent and there are no opaque pixels behind it, you see a kind of default grid indicating that this part of the image is "transparent", like in the centre here:

[image: Transparency example]

Is there a way to change the look of this grid, or are you stuck with the default "light grey/dark grey"?  I'm open to solutions even if the functionality has only recently been added in development versions of GIMP.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`Edit > Preferences > Display > Transparency >` Check style and Check size.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  It's a shame you can't actually control the colors of the checkered pattern beyond a few predetermined settings, but it's still probably good enough.

Comment: Don't miss `Edit > Preferences > Default Grid` also!